# Why isn't my input group displaying properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using an input group to set up an input that allows users to type in a number or edit the number by pressing the plus and minus buttons. For some reason, I can't get them to display in my project. I copied the code to a test page and it displayed there. Also, the text input for the number isn't responding to the CSS that I have set for it as well. What is the issue with my input? I have provided the code below.

This shows up in the css for both buttons as well, but i'm not sure if it has to do with the issue:

```
.input-group:not(.has-validation)>.dropdown-toggle:nth-last-child(n+3), .input-group:not(.has-validation)>:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle):not(.dropdown-menu)
```

[image]

```
<div class="input-group" id="changePrice${index}">
  <span class="input-group-btn" id="minus${index}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="minus" data- 
     field="quant[1]">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" name="quant[1]" id="numberInput${index}" value="${index}"
  min="0" max="200">
  <span class="input-group-btn" id="plus${index}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data- 
      field="quant[1]">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="plus${index}"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

```
.center {
  margin: 40px auto;
  display: none;
}

.center button:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
}
.center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin: -181px 80px;
}
#numberInput{
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 23px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Did you inspect the browser for those inputs? Maybe your glyphicons are not loaded properly hence the button is too small and has no content in it. Try adding text in your buttons and see if they are visible, if they are, glyphicons haven't been loaded.

Comment: Yes. I messed around with the elements' width and height and nothing appeared

Comment: I even removed the icon and still nothing

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's much better than trying to guess where the problem lies.

Comment: I ended up just going with another similar input that ended up working. Thank you all for the help!